# Input[type = 'text'] accept alphabets only instead of alphabets and whitespaces

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make my input text field accept alphabets only and space(at least one white space), not only alphabets, i use this expression but only alphabets works but if I put spaces between the text, doesnt work.

```
const isAlphabet = (input) => {
    const re = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    return re.test(input);
  }
``
```

Comment: See [Reference - What does this regex mean?](/q/22937618/4642212) and the [regex tag wiki](/tags/regex/info) and use regex debuggers like [RegEx101](//regex101.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let change `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/` for `/^[a-z A-Z]+$/`. i saw that someone used `\s` instead of  , so i'm still sending my answer, since expression proposed by me is shorter, better performing (due to handling only space) plus u will gain additional knowledge, how to handle spaces in different way.

Comment: wow, let me try this too

Answer (score 1):

Use [`\s`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet) (including space, tab, form feed, line feed, and other Unicode spaces)

```js
const isAlphabet = (input) => {
    const re = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
    return re.test(input);
}
```